Marquee stutters only in iOS Chrome - but fine on Desktop and Android
Fairly new to CSS, I spent a long time trying to figure out how to do a nice smooth text ticker, and one that resizes neatly from desktop to mobile?
The scroller is pulled in where "textticker" / "textticker" appears, and the JS is at the bottom.
It seems to generally work fine on desktop. But when I try it on iPhone, the text scrolls, jitters, or suddenly starts over breaking the smooth scroll effect.
Any ideas how to fix?


body {
    background-color:;
  padding: 0px;
      margin:0px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: #333333; /* Set default text color to #333333 */
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   .container {
    margin: 0px;
   width: 100%;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }



/* product starts <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

/* Product container */
/* Product container */
.product-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80svh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative; /* Allows positioning of product-info */
}
/* Product inner */
.product-inner {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* Align the product-image to the left */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically center the content */
  padding: 0px;
}




/* Flex container for product-stats and product-ticker */
.product-info {
  position: absolute; /* Keeps the container in the top right */
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stacks child elements vertically */
  width: 400px; /* Fixed width for both elements */
  gap: 10px; /* Adds space between the product-stats and product-ticker */
}


/* Product ticker */
.product-ticker {
  width: 100%; /* Takes full width of the flex container */
  border: 1px solid #333333;

  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  --gap: 5px;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap);

  font-family: 'BookmanRoman';
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: black;
line-height: 1;
letter-spacing: -0.6px;
}

.product-ticker textticker {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap);
  animation: scroll 30s linear infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    font-family: 'BookmanRoman';
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -0.6px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
  }
}


    /* Outer table container */
    .outer-table-container {
      border: 10px solid white;
      width: 100%; /* Fixed width for the outer table */
      background-color: white;
      box-sizing: border-box;


    }


    /* Outer table styling */
    .outer-table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%; /* Ensure outer table takes up the full container width */
    }

    /* Outer table cells */
    .outer-table td {
      border: none;
      padding: 5px; /* Match the cellpadding of the inner table */
    }

   

     /* Button styling for the 'BUY NOW' button */
     .product-buy-now-btn {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background: silver; /* Green background */
      border-radius: 0px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      color: blue;
      border: 2px solid blue; /* Blue border */
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-family: 'BookmanJF';
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    /* Button hover effect */
    .product-buy-now-btn:hover {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white !important;
    }

    /* Styling for the link that wraps the button */
    .product-buy-now-link {
      display: block; /* Make the link fill the entire cell */
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline from the link */
    }



/* product ends <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */


 






/* <<<<<<<<< MEDIA QUERIES <<<<<<<<< */
/* <<<<<<<<< MEDIA QUERIES <<<<<<<<< */
/* <<<<<<<<< MEDIA QUERIES <<<<<<<<< */

@media (width <= 768px) {



  /* Header section <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

   


  /* product  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

    /* Product container */
    .product-container {
      width: 100vw;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column; /* Ensure divs stack in mobile view */
      align-items: center;    /* Center items horizontally */
      justify-content: flex-start; /* Align items to the top */
      position: static;
       box-sizing: border-box;


    }

        .product-info {
          width: 100vw;
          height: auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column; /* Ensure divs stack in mobile view */
          align-items: center;    /* Center items horizontally */
          justify-content: flex-start; /* Align items to the top */
          position: static;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          gap: 0px;
    
        }
      
  
    /* Product inner */
    .product-inner {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 12svh;
      margin-bottom: 5svh;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* Product stats */
    .product-stats {
      position: static; /* Keep it in the normal document flow */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0; /* Ensure there's no extra margin pushing it */
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;

    }

/* Product ticker */
.product-ticker {
  width: 100%; /* Takes full width of the flex container */
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color:;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

  /* ends   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

  }
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 
</head>
<body>

 
  
    <div class="container" style="background-color: ;">



   <!-- Product -->
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-inner">
        </div>

        <!-- New Flex Container for product-stats and product-ticker -->
        <div class="product-info">
            <div class="product-stats">
                <!-- Outer Table -->
                <div class="outer-table-container">
                    <table class="outer-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            
                            lorem ipsum text
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                     
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Cell with clickable button styled link -->
                                <a href="https://example.com" class="product-buy-now-link" target="_blank">
                                    <button class="product-buy-now-btn">
                                            BUY NOW
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Ticker directly below the product-stats >> text in js at end-->
            <div class="product-ticker">
                 <textticker>
  </textticker>
    <textticker>
  </textticker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                  </div>


 




<!-- Smooth scroll script -->
<script>
    function smoothScroll(targetId) {
      const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
      if (target) {
        const targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        const distance = targetPosition - 50; // Optional offset for smoother position
        const duration = 2000; // Increased duration for slower scroll
        let start = null;

        // Easing function for smoother ease-in-out effect (Quartic)
        function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
          t /= d / 2;
          if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
          t -= 2;
          return -c / 2 * (t * t * t * t - 2) + b;
        }

        // The animation loop
        function animation(currentTime) {
          if (start === null) start = currentTime;
          const timeElapsed = currentTime - start;
          const run = easeInOutQuart(timeElapsed, startPosition, distance, duration);
          window.scrollTo(0, run);
          if (timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animation);
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('shop-link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      smoothScroll('shop');
    });
  </script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>


<script>
    // Define the text content once
    const tickerText = "This is the text ticker. It mostly works ok on desktop and android, but stutters and skips on iphone &#8226; This is the text ticker. It mostly works on desktop and android, but stutters and skips on iphone &#8226;";

    // Find all <textticker> elements and insert the text content
    document.querySelectorAll('textticker').forEach(el => {
        el.innerHTML = tickerText;
    });
</script>
 

</body>
</html>




The effect is more often called and referred-to as Marquee

Can you provide a recoded demo gif of what happens, when you resize with your question.

hey there, if anyone could be kind enough to view this on chrome on iOS - it happens every time when I test. If you just let it run, after a few seconds - when the text is about to repeat - it stutters and or flashes. - it only happens on iOS, it's fine on chrome desktop and android.  Any tips appreciated, super confused by this. I've read about using webkit code lines in CSS / hardware acceleration nothing seems to help.
